# cocos2d-x 3.17.2 utils::captureScreen failed assertion on iOS 13.1.3 on my iPad mini 5th

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, ios13, cocos2d-x-3.17

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.17.2 and running my App on iPad mini 5th iOS 13.1.3.

When I call utils::captureScreen, it causes assertion failure.

> _validateGetBytes:29: failed assertion `CPU access for textures with MTLResourceStorageModePrivate storage mode is disallowed.'

It seems like a MTLResourceStorageMode related problem.

But I can't find out how to fix this.

I run the same code on iOS 11.4.1 iPod touch 6th, and on iOS 12.4.3 iPad mini 2nd, but these 2 devices don't cause this problem, they run perfect.

Here is my code.

```
 string path = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath().append("screenshot.jpg");
 Label *path_lbl = Label::createWithSystemFont(path, "", 20.0);
 const char* filename = path_lbl->getString().c_str();
 utils::captureScreen([&](bool succeed,const std::string &fileName){}, filename);
```

and assertion failed on the line: ccUtils.cpp: Line 105

> glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer.get());

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I post the same question here. [https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/utils-capturescreen-failed-assertion-on-ios-13-1-3/48140](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/utils-capturescreen-failed-assertion-on-ios-13-1-3/48140)  Please see this.

Answer (score 0):

Something about the underlying Metal implementation of `glReadPixels()` is violating the Metal rules for memory access as of iOS 13.1 (and it's not fixed as of 13.3.1).

The good news is, this is a debugging check only. When not attached to the Xcode debugger, it will "just work." To get Xcode to let it slide, you can:

1. Go to Edit Scheme
2. Select the Run options in the sidebar
3. Go to the Options tab
4. Disable Metal API Validation

[image]